# scope of $_POST[] , trying to access $_POST[] variable, getting the undefined index error

Tags: php, html, forms, post, scope

I have these two forms that submits to different blocks of the same script. i am unable to access variable of one block in other, though both variables are in same script.

html form :(1.php)

```
<html>
  <form method="POST" action="2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    </br>
    Choose a user name:</font>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save and Proceed">
  </form>
</html>
```

2.php:

```
 <?php
    $name=$_POST['username'];
    if ((isset($_POST['username'])) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'Save and Proceed'))
    {
        $name=$_POST['username'];
        echo $name;
        if($name=='azra')
        {
        ?>
        <html>
          <form method="POST" action="2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"></br>
            enter age:</font>
            <input type="text" name="age">
            <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="done">
          </form>
        </html>
        <?php
        }
    }

    if((isset($_POST['age'])) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'done'))
    {
        $age=$_POST['age'];
        echo $age;
        if($age==25)
        {
            echo "hi" .$name;
            echo "your age is ". $age;
            echo"you are eligible";
        }
    }   

  ?>
```

How do I access `$_POST['username']` in the code following the html form in the same script? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use `<?php echo $_POST['username'] ?>` , i m really not sure wat you need and do??

Comment: Sidenote: you have invalid HTML. You have a closing `</font>` tag but not an opening `<font>` tag.

Comment: that was a typo error sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well you want to pass username twice.
Than you can use hidden input, which is not visible (only transports data):

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 3):

On the second form you can use a [hidden input](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms07.htm), i.e.:

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="$name">
```

Example:

```
<?php

    $name=$_POST['username'];
    if (!empty($_POST['username']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Save and Proceed'))
    {
        $name=$_POST['username'];
        echo $name;
        if($name=='azra')
        {
            echo <<< LOL
         <html>
        <form method="POST" action="2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"></br>
        enter age:</font> <input type="text" name="age">
         <input type="hidden" name="username" value="$name">
        <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="done">
        </form>
        </html>
LOL;
        }
    }

    if((isset($_POST['age'])) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'done'))
    {
        $age=$_POST['age'];
        echo $age;
        if($age==25)
        {
            echo "hi" .$name;
            echo "your age is ". $age;
            echo"you are eligible";
        }
    }   

?>
```

Comment: I love the heredoc identifier. +1

Comment: I always use it, I don't like escaping quotes, double-quotes, it's time wasting, +1 to u 2 ;)